# Custom bitcoin confirmation process

Tags: bitcoin-core, development, confirmations, payment, bip32-hd-wallets

I am implementing a payment module for bitcoins.

I have the following case. I need customers to be able to pay in bitcoins. But for some reasons I cannot use existing solutions like **Bitpay**.

Therefore I have thought and ended up with the following solution.

1. We have a private key wallet of HD type, so we can generate child addresses from our master key.
2. When a user tries to pay in Bitcoins we are generating a new address and display it to the user.
3. We associate an address with an order id
4. A daemon running in background is checking pending orders requesting information from Blockchain for a concrete address and checking whether this address received amount equal to an order total sum.
5. In case there are more than X confirmations we are setting a status of an order to PAID

I wonder whether this is acceptable solutions or maybe there are some better ways to implement custom bitcoin payments ?

I would be great for any suggestions and help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are existing solutions that handle payment processing for you. You can use [BTCPayServer](https://github.com/btcpayserver/btcpayserver) which has an API that is similar to BitPay's API.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer could you provide any other solutions ?